# How to create a Scroll between two TD of a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a table which has n number of columns in table. Since there are many columns of same nature , it is asked to scroll between them. Below Picture will make it clean.
[image]

Here Models Needs a scroll bar which will only scroll Model in table.
How can I achieve such result with HTML tables.

Comment: try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/7/

Comment: Yeah Ananad ,correct Only I want to know can I make another column at right which is not scrollable , for example in JSfiddle Can I add Item 5 which is static as Months

Comment: try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/9Yp8g/5/

Comment: Cool . Its great to see ur skills bro. Just wanted to check will it be easy if we create such layout without table , I mean with divs , span , li etc . Can we make such an layout . If You Guide I will try.

Comment: hey kumar pallav is answer worked for you?

Comment: Ur answer did helped bro. but at end I had to start using dataTable plugin of JQuery

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this please check this one fiddle:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Yp8g/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="tbl">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">
                    <div class="col col1">
                        <ul>
                            <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li>

                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li>

                        </ul>                   
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col2">
                        <div class="innerdiv">
                        <ul>
                            <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li><li>Six</li><li>Seven</li>
                            <li>Eight</li><li>Nine</li><li>Ten</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li><li>Four</li><li>Five</li><li>Six</li><li>Seven</li>
                            <li>Eight</li><li>Nine</li><li>Ten</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col3">
                        <ul>
                        <li>one</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>one</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
li{display:inline;margin-right:10px;}
        .tbl{display:table;width:20%;}
        .row{display:table-row;}
        .cell{display:table-cell;width:100%;}
        .w{width:20%;}
        .col {display:table-cell;}
        .col1{width:50%;float:left;}
        .col2{width:20%;float:left;overflow-x:scroll;}
        .col3{width:30%;float:right;}
        .innerdiv{width:500px;}
```